# Upsert query is not updating the the records in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to Upsert into the target table from temp table but
My upsert query is not updating the records in postgresql. Although it is inserting but not updating.
Please find below query:

```
Insert into store 
Select t.* from store_temp 
where t.id not in (select a. Id 
from store a) on conflict(id) 
DO
Update
Set source = EXCLUDED.Source
```

Any helping hand would be really appreciated.

Comment: You where clause eliminates any conflicts (other than those caused by concurrent activity) so there is expected to be nothing that needs updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax looks correct, but I don't think you want the `where` clause.  Instead:

```
Insert into store ( . . . )
    select . . .
    from store_temp t
    on conflict (id) do update
        set source = EXCLUDED.Source;
```

The `. . .` are for the column list.  I recommend being explicit in `insert`s.

Then you need to be sure that `id` is declared as the primary key or at least has a unique constraint or index.